# How to use SED without a file with an env var?

Tags: bash, shell, sed, environment-variables

Is it possible to substitute a thing in env var with SED?

```
$ a='aoeua'
$ sed 's@a@o@g' <$a
bash: aoeua: No such file or directory
$ env|grep "SHELL"
SHELL=/bin/bash
```

The output I want is

```
ooeuo
```

replacing each `a` in `'aoeua'` with `o`.

Comment: I've edited your question to explain what output you're looking for, based on the accepted answer.  The original question showed us what *didn't* work, but didn't clearly tell us what you're trying to do.  (Laurence guessed correctly.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use echo:

```
$ echo "$a" | sed 's@a@o@g'
```

In bash you can also do simple substitutions with the `${parameter/pattern/string}` syntax. For example:

```
$ v='aoeua'
$ echo ${v/a/o}
ooeua
```

Note that this only replaces the first occurrence of the pattern.

Comment: For **global substitution** we can do `echo ${v//a/o}`.

Comment: @JaypalSingh Thanks! I don't see any mention of that in the man page, but it looks like it works.

Comment: Yea, it's not that well written. This is what it says - `${parameter/pattern/string} The pattern is expanded to produce a pattern just as in pathname expansion.  Parameter is expanded and the longest match of pattern against its value is replaced with string.  **If pattern begins with /, all matches of pattern are replaced with string**.  Normally only the first match is replaced.`

Comment: @JaypalSingh Ah, so it is documented! I guess I hadn't read through that entire paragraph (at least not since this was added?). If they had multiple header lines, the way they do for `#` and `##` (or `%` and `%%`) it might make this more obvious.

Comment: Yea :) the problem is all the bash goodies on `man page` are stated in a way that they can easily be oversighted. Since I am very new to this, I have stated making notes so that I can refer those instead of `man`. Though this [guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/abs-guide.pdf) is really good.

Answer (score 17):

This might work for you:

```
a='aoeua'
sed 's@a@o@g' <<<$a
ooeuo
```

`<<<$a` is a [here-string](http://www.tldp.net/LDP/abs/html/x17647.html)

Comment: I needed to do replacement without echoing (use in PS1 variable). this was helpful to me

Comment: was looking for this for a while...very nice